# Why does the acceleration derivative of the function looks this way?

Tags: functions, derivatives

In the lecture provided by Imperial College on Coursera the teacher explained that , at first, we draw a tangent line at every point. For example, while the speed increases, the tangent line is positive - however, , as we can see from the graph, the orange graph below is going down. 
I can't get why the gradient (orange graph) is going down, while the speed increases.

[image: c]

Comment: The speed is increasing, but it is increasing less and less; hence the orange curve is decreasing. More accurately, acceleration is defined to be the derivative of the velocity. So, initially, the slope of the speed (white graph) is positive and very steep. So, the acceleration starts out very positive. Later, although the speed increases, the slope of the graph decreases (it still has positive slope, but it is becoming more flat), hence, the acceleration decreases from a high positive value to a low positive value, and becomes $0$. Try to continue with this line of reasoning.

Comment: I've got your point. Just to clear that out, the decreasing graph of acceleration in the beginning represents that the white speed-time graph at some point has continued to increase but with lower acceleration. Am I right?

Comment: Following this idea, now I can''t understand why the Jerk is negative in the beginning.

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: Could you give me a hint with the Jerk graph? Why is it negative in the beginning?

Comment: Take a look at the acceleration graph at the beginning. The SLOPE is initially negative. So, the jerk is negative in the beginning. Slightly afterwards, the slope of the acceleration is becoming less negative, and that is what the jerk graph is doing Basically, you need to be familiar with how to sketch $f'$ from the graph of $f$. Always ask yourself this: is the SLOPE positive or negative? is the SLOPE increasing or decreasing? (the derivative is by definition, just the slope. so it doesn't matter whether the function is positive or negative; just look at what the slope is doing)

Comment: I got my mistake. Thank you, highly appreciated.

Comment: Refer to a real-life model: If you’ve got your gas pedal pressed to the floor and then ease off a bit, your car’s speed will still be increasing, but the rate at which it increases has dropped.

Answer (score 1):

The orange curve is the slope of the white curve.  At the left edge the white curve is increasing rapidly, so the orange curve is rather positive.  As time increases to $0.8$ of the first division the slope of the white curve is decreasing, so the value of the orange curve is also decreasing.  At about $0.8$ division the white curve is at a local maximum, so is horizontal.  The orange curve is zero at that point.  Then the white curve starts to decrease, so the orange curve is negative and so on.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds really clear. Following this idea, now I can''t understand why the Jerk is negative in the beginning.

Comment: The jerk is the derivative of the acceleration.  As the acceleration is decreasing, the jerk is negative.